# UpdatePanel contol and moving to top of page

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, scroll

I have an asp.net page that is using an UpdatePanel control. When you're on the page and you click the continue button, the page does a partial refresh and you're left in the same scroll position you were before the refresh. How do I ensure that on partial refreshes with the UpdatePanel control that you return to the top of the page.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is a javascript call to move the scroll to the top of the page:

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

You can wire an event handler to the completion of your AJAX call and add that javascript to your event handler.

Comment: For ASP.Net, wiring the end request event handler is like this:

<script type="text/javascript">
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
</script>

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you do it using jquery and the updatepanel

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var pageRequestManager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

   pageRequestManager.add_endRequest(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    });
</script>
```